# python subprocess cannot find existing dll

Tags: python, dll, subprocess, gdal

Some time ago i wrote a small tool to calculate raster tiles, which worked fine.
Now after some months of being untouched i had to use it again and suddenly it spits out some missing .dll errors.

I have put the corresponding code bit below

```
    print('Die default tilesize is 5000x5000px')
    tilelenght = 5000
    x = 0
    y = 0
    print("calculation tile")
    for i in range(0, width, tilelenght):
        y = 0
        for j in range(0, height, tilelenght):
            gdaltranString = f'gdal_translate -of GTIFF -srcwin {i}, {j}, {tilelenght}, {tilelenght} {input_filepath} {output_filepath}{x}_{y}.tif'
            subprocess.run(gdaltranString)
            y = y+1
        x = x+1
    print("tile calculated")
```

Console prints out :

```
Input file size is 60000, 30000
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdalplugins\ogr_FileGDB.dll
126: Module not found.
```

So far so good, now come the wierd part. When i check this *exact* location on my harddrive, i find that the org_FileGDB.dll is there. To make things even mor econfusing, the tiles get calculated but for some very unclear reason the colors get warped, but lets just focus on the .dll problem for now.

Which begs the question what is wrong here?

**EDIT 1 Machine Specs**

Windows 10 64 Bit.

Python 3.7.2 64-Bit, one and only Python interpreter.

I have Qgis 3.10.2 on this machine, and Qgis ships it's own python interpreter, but afaik it is sealed of and never interferred with anything before, so IMO it's unlikely to be the source of the error.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of python installed? Is it possible that you have the module installed for your python37 located at "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37" but actually trying to run the code using another instance of python?

Comment: I have edited the question to give more information in this regard. I did not tinker arround with the interpreter in any way, nor did install another one.

Comment: Check this issue: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198289/does-gohlke-gdal-break-command-line-gdal-ogr-in-windoiws It might help.

Comment: Sorry for the long pause, i did not rly have time at work to further investigate this issue. I checked out the suggeted post but to no avail